# what's the different between the codes as below in performance and why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have written

```
    change_column_null :my_Table, :column_name, false, false
```

and someone told me to change it to

```
   my_Table.where('column_name IS NULL').update_all(column_name: false)
```

he told Because as is, you're running the ALTER table command more, and that will take longer than it should on the production database.
both works,I wanna know what's the different in running these two.

Comment: They do very different things. Perhaps asking the person who told you to do it would help since we don't know your application. Also, researching the two commands in your database documentation is your first step to learn what the commands do, which, with your insight into the application, should help you understand why you want to do it. See "[ask]".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first statement will alter your db schema (DDL) while the other is a query (SQL).

Although they both work, they accomplish different things

Anyways, the first one is implemented by the adapter so it's optimized for the particular db you are using